# How to store and call a simple mongodb procedure

Tags: mongodb

I often call the same commands in MongoDb command shell, for example :

```
db.user().find().pretty();
```

How would you store and call back this command ?

Ideally converting it to something like this :

```
db.findp( 'user' );
```

Comment: If you are intending to do this from a language like php or python etc it should be known it comes with many many flaws and draw backs, however, to answer the actual question: it depends on what language you are using

Comment: In the command shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is NOT what your looking for, now that I read your question again: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/server-side-javascript/

Instead you are looking to modify the console in such a manner to make your life easier.

I should note, right now, that there is actually an extension which can do this sort of auto-formatting for you made by 10gen: https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker

However if you wish to modify the files behind MongoDBs console a little more then you will need to do some manual labour.

There is a `rc` script in your home directory called `.mongorc.js`. In this file you can place any custom code you like (as @Asya mentioned) and it will actually become a command within the console.

In you `rc` file you could place a function like:

```
DB.prototype.pfind = function(col){
    return this[col].find().pretty();
};
```

Or you could write:

```
DBCollection.prototype.pfind = function(){
    return this.find().pretty();
};
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
db.pfind('users');
```

Or with the second command:

```
db.users.pfind();
```

Of course this method is for Linux, I am unsure about Windows, however, Windows should have an `rc` type script somewhere I believe.

Comment: why would he link a file to ~/.mongorc.js - why not put the javascript into the file ~/.mongodb.rc?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky dunno I just got that command from the github repo tbh, I couldn't remember how to do it properly and didn't check.

Comment: just remove the whole ln bit - the javascript goes into a file in your home directory called .mongorc.js and that's it.

Comment: It works ! Note that on Windows, I've located the '.mongorc.js' file in my main user folder.